# $scope.showDefaultState` evaluates to undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why does `$scope.showDefaultState` evaluate to undefined despite being set in the if statement?

How do I get it to not evaluate to undefined but capture the "true" value?

```
// Determine if user has signed up in past
$cordovaNativeStorage.getItem("userPicture").then(function (value) {
  $scope.userInfo.userPicture = value;
}, function (error) {
  $log.log(error);
});
$cordovaNativeStorage.getItem("userProfile").then(function (value) {
  $scope.userInfo.userProfile = value;
}, function (error) {
  $log.log(error);
});
$cordovaNativeStorage.getItem("userSelectedCategories").then(function (value) {
  $scope.userInfo.userSelectedCategories = value;
}, function (error) {
  $log.log(error);
});

if($scope.userInfo.userPicture != null && $scope.userInfo.userProfile != null && $scope.userInfo.userSelectedCategories != null) {
  $scope.showDefaultState = true;
}

console.log($scope.showDefaultState);

if($scope.showDefaultState == null) {

// stuff goes here... the code in this block always runs
}
```

Comment: Its probably null because the promise has not resolved by the time the if condition that sets showDefaultState=true is executed. Try giving a timeout value and then see if it helps?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I would prefer not to use a timeout, are there any other alternatives?

Comment: @clever_bassi no, that's not a good way to wait for a promise to resolve. You need to chain your functions into something like `Promise.all`, then upon resolve, your `showDefaultState` is set, or null and you can proceed.

Comment: Thanks Sterling. I'm new to this so thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine the promises and evaluate all at once. [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

```
var p1 = $cordovaNativeStorage.getItem("userPicture");
var p2 = $cordovaNativeStorage.getItem("userProfile");
var p3 = $cordovaNativeStorage.getItem("userSelectedCategories");

$q.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(function (data) {
    $scope.userInfo.userPicture = data[0];
    $scope.userInfo.userProfile = data[1]; ;
    $scope.userInfo.userSelectedCategories = data[2];
    if ($scope.userInfo.userPicture != null && $scope.userInfo.userProfile != null && $scope.userInfo.userSelectedCategories != null) {
        $scope.showDefaultState = true;
    }

}).catch (function (err) {
    console.log(err.message); // some coding error in handling happened
});
```